# what is wrong with Ptolemy's proof of the Euclid's fifth Postulate?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

This snapshot is from Heath on Euclid Vol 1 page 205.

Here he is discussing how Ptolemy attempted to prove Euclid's fifth postulate:

[image]

Here is the text:

"Let AB, CD be parallel, and let FG meet them. I say that FG does not make the
interior angles on the same side greater than two right angles.

For, if the angles AFG, CGF are greater than two right angles, the
remaining angles BFG, DGF are less than two right angles.

But the same two angles are also greater than two right angles; for AF,
CG are no more parallel than FB, GD, so that, if the straight line falling on
AF, CG makes the interior angles greater than two right angles, the straight line
falling on FB, GD will also make the interior angles greater than two right angles.

But the same angles are also less than two right angles; for the four
angles AFG, CGF, BFG, DGF are equal to four right angles:
which is impossible."

First Ptolemy proves the above and then Euclid's postulate follows.

Then Heath says that Proclus refuted this by pointing out that when Ptolemy says: *"for AF and CG are no more parallel than FB and GD, so that, if the straight line falling on AF, CG makes the interior angles greater than two right angles..."* he is using the fact that we can only draw a **unique** parallel line to a given line through a given point and this fact is equivalent to Euclid's fifth (in Euclidean context) so Ptolemy is using what needs to be proved.

My question is this last bit. How does what Ptolemy say imply uniqueness of the parallel line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ptolemy's argument is.

Suppose you have a parallel line where the angles on the left are less than two right angles and the angles on the right are more.  Now you can construct a line that has the same angles but mirror reversed, with the angles on the right the same less than two right angles and the angles on the left the same more.  By symmetry both lines are "equally" parallel.

Ptolemy assumes they can't both be parallel so neither are and so unless the angles are equal to two right angles the line won't be parallel.

But what he *doesn't* consider is ....  maybe they both *CAN* be parallel.